# Calculating average value of a signal

Tags: electricity

The formula is 
$$
\frac{1}{T}\int_{a}^{b}S(t) .dt
$$
I understand how the integral gives us the area under the curve, but average means the sum of all over how much all is, the integral here is the sum of all $S(t)dt$ between $a$ and $b$ but shouldn't it really be just the sum of the $S(t)$'s between $a$ and $b$ divided by $T$?

Comment: Your suggestion has the wrong units for the average value of the signal (namely, the units in your suggestion are signal amplitude per unit time, while the average value should just have units of signal amplitude).

Comment: honestly I'm asking for an explanation and for someone to tell me what I'm missing here, thank you anyways!

Comment: @probably_someone, there's a $\rm dt$ term in the numerator and a $T$ term in the denominator, so no time units in the final result.

Comment: @ThePhoton What I was talking about was his suggestion of "just the sum of the $S(t)$s between $a$ and $b$ divided by $T$."

Comment: Think about this: If you wanted to take a sum (rather than an integral) of S(t) between a and b, how many terms would there be in your sum?

Comment: @sammygerbil Not quite, I think. You could, for example, think about choosing some partition $P$ of $[a,b]$ and writing $\sum_{t_i\in P} S(t_i)/T$. Of course, this does not correspond to the average, but it does correspond to a sum of $S(t)$s between $a$ and $b$ divided by $T$.

Comment: @ThePhoton infinite i guess

Comment: @probably_someone Yes I see what you mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To take an average of a few discrete data points, we would add all the data points and divide by the number of data points. If you had a time interval $T$ divided into steps of size $\Delta t$, the number of data points would be $N=T/\Delta t$. Therefore, the average of measurements at those times would be
$$\frac{S(t=1)+S(t=2)+...S(t=N)}{N}=\frac{S(t=1)\Delta t+S(t=2)\Delta t+...S(t=N)\Delta t}{T}$$
Now think of taking the limit that $\Delta t$ becomes infinitesimal and you get the integral.

Comment: bless you, nicely explained